# Powershell Find and replace first line of CSV only

Tags: powershell

I need to read in a CSV file and find replace certain characters from the first line of the file only. I have used foreach-object however this processes the entire file. Any thought on how this can best be achieved.

Here is the code :

```
Get-Content c:\output.csv | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "objectGUID", 'StudentID' } | Set-Content c:\output2.csv
```

Comment: How are you reading the file and do the replacement get-content?

Comment: Get-Content c:\output.csv | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "objectGUID", 'StudentID' } | Set-Content c:\output2.csv

Comment: You cannot re-write the first line of the file in-place, so there isn't any way around reading and re-writing the entire file.  That being said, it is possible to avoid processing it a line at a time.  how big is this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't fix the problem of having to process the entire file, but should substantially reduce the time it takes to do it if it's a substantially large file.

```
$Updated = $false

Get-Content c:\output.csv -ReadCount 1000 | 
 ForEach-Object {
  if ($Updated)
    { 
      $_ | Add-Content c:\output2.csv 
    }

  else {
         $_[0] = $_[0] -replace "objectGUID", 'StudentID'
         $_ | Set-Content c:\output2.csv
         $Updated = $true
       }

}
```

Edit: if it's only 3000 rows this should be sufficient:

```
$FileContent = Get-Content c:\output.csv 
$FileContent[0] = $FileContent[0] -replace 'objectGUID', 'StudentID'
$FileContent | Set-Content c:\output2.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Get-Content makes this simple enough if all you want to do is change the first line of a text file.

```
GC c:\output.csv|select -first 1|%{$_ -replace "objectGUID", 'StudentID'}|Out-File C:\Output2.csv
GC C:\output.csv -readcount 1000|Select -skip 1|Out-File C:\Output2.csv -Append
```

That will pull the first line only, replacing the text you wanted and write it to a new file (assuming you don't already have an Output2.csv file). After that it reads in the rest of the file skipping the first line and adds that to the same file. You can delete the original file after that and rename the output file if you feel the need.

Comment: I believe that second line is going to skip the first 1000 records of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply however the final file (output2) only contains one line. It is also no longer in CSV format, i.e. the headers are no longer different columns. Thanks

Comment: mjolinor's totally right, that skipped the first 1000 lines of the file. I guess I need more coffee before I answer questions today. Sorry!